# $g^{-1}$'(2) when g(t)=$t^5+t^3$

Tags: calculus

$g^{-1}$'(2)

g(t)=$t^5+t^3$

If I understand this correctly I shall take the primitive function of the inverse and calculate t=2 but I did not get the correct answer which should be $\frac{1}{8}$

Comment: You could just use the formula (third displayed equation) [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation).

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of $g^{-1}(t^5+t^3)$ = t  is  $(5t^3 + 3t^2)*g^{-1}(t^5+t^3) = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Using $g^{-1}(g(t)) = t$ and differentiating wrt $t$,

$$\dfrac{d}{d\,g(t)}\left[g^{-1}(g(t))\right] = \dfrac{1}{g'(t)}$$

We need to find $t$ so that $g(t) = 2$. So we solve $t^5 + t^3 = 2$. This gives us $t=1$ as the only real root.

$$\dfrac{d}{d\,g(t)}\left[g^{-1}(g(t))\right]|_{g(t) = 2} = \dfrac{1}{g'(1)} = \frac{1}{8}$$

Answer (score 0):

We know that:

$$f^{-1}(f(x))=x$$
put $f(x)=x^5+x^3$ to get
$$f^{-1}(x^5+x^3)=x$$
Let $x=1$
$$f^{-1}(2)=1$$

Therefore $1$ is the answer you are looking for

If You want derivative, simply use:

$$(f^{-1})'(x)=\frac{1}{f'(x)}$$
Therefore,$$(f^{-1})'(x^5+x^3)=\frac{1}{f'(x^5+x^3)\times(5x^4+3x^2)}$$
$$(f^{-1})'(2)=\frac{1}{8f'(2)}$$

which should give you $\frac{1}{736}$

Comment: OP want the derivative of the inverse, evaluated at $2$, I think.

Comment: Lemme edit @DavidMitra

Comment: $f^{-1}'(2)=1/f '(1)=1/8$